# Excel - adding pure months to date

Tags: excel, date

I have a column [A] with date values (MM-DD-yYYY). I want to have another column [B] with a month value that is equal to 11 months from [A]. By months, I mean a simple count of 11 months, not 30days*11 months. This results in a [B] value that is always a calendar month -1 from [A]. So if [A1] holds the value of "11-20-2015" I would like [B1] to hold a value of "October". If [A2] holds a value of "03-29-2014", I would like [B2] to hold a value of "February".

I can't really come up with an efficient way to do this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [EDATE function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/edate-function-1586b161-4361-4a6d-939b-9d96eae962a8) adds a number of months easily.

```
=edate(A1, 11)
```

Use a custom number format of `mmmm` to display *October* or *February*. Use a custom number format of `mmm` to display *Oct* or *Feb*.

Note that this is definitively 11 months in the future, not 1 month in the past.

Comment: I forgot about this one.  It is good to see you correcting my mistakes again.:)